# Which user should be used as the ECL PrivilegedUserName

Tags: ecl, security

Are there any security risks with using the MTSUSer? If so, what are the risks (and why)?

The documentation says the following:

> Make sure the user specified in `<PrivilegedUserName>` has the following
>   rights and permissions:
>
> - Grant the user access to the Publications which use media stored in a    CMIS system—go to System Administration > Users , open a user and
>     edit the User membership scope.
> - Grant the user Component Management    rights and Schema Management rights in each of these Publications.
> - Grant the user Read and Write permissions on the Folder specified by    the  element.
> - Grant the user Read permissions on the Building Blocks Folder.

MTSUSer clearly has these rights, but it is not clear to me whether this is safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MTSuser, that will work.

Some considerations

- The privileged user will create Tridion items: the ECL schema, stub folders and stub compontents. Maybe you don't want te MTSuser to create any items.
- ECL does not need MTSuser access, so why grant it this special superadmin rights?
- The MTUser has a lot of access, do you trust your ECL provider with that? But you would not install ECL providers from untrusted sources anyway.